# Add Months in a For Loop using PostgreSQL PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql

I am learning about for loops and trying to create a PL/pgSQL block using PostgreSQL that will generate a payment schedule. This loop runs for 12 months until there is a 0 balance and will display the date due every month.

This is what I have so far but the month portion is not adding in the for loop, it only adds once.

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
    start_date DATE := '01-Jan-2021';
    payment_due_date DATE;
    due_date VARCHAR(25);
    mon_pay_amt NUMERIC := 10;
    total_mon_amt NUMERIC := 12;
    bal_num NUMERIC :=0;

BEGIN
bal_num := mon_pay_amt * total_mon_amt;
due_date := start_date; 
RAISE NOTICE 'Total Amount due in 12 Months: %', to_char(bal_num, '$999.99');
FOR i IN 1..total_mon_amt LOOP
    bal_num := bal_num - mon_pay_amt;
    payment_due_date := start_date + INTERVAL '1 MONTH';
    RAISE NOTICE 'Payment Number: %', i ||' '|| 'Due Date: ' ||payment_due_date|| ' Payment Amount : ' || to_char(mon_pay_amt, '$99.99') ||' '||
    'Balance ' || to_char(bal_num, '$999.99');

END LOOP;
END $$;
```

[image]

Comment: That is because you keep adding `'1 month'`  to `start_date` which is fixed at '01-Jan-2021'.  You need to use the `i` counter in the loop. Something like: `start_date + INTERVAL  i::varchar || ' ' || MONTH'`.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Would work like this:

```sql
DO
$$ 
DECLARE
   start_date date := '2021-01-01';  -- always use ISO date format
   payment_due_date date := start_date;
   mon_pay_amt numeric := 10;
   mon_pay_amt_text text :=  to_char(mon_pay_amt, '$90.99');
   total_mon_amt int := 12;
   bal_num numeric := mon_pay_amt * total_mon_amt;
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE 'Total Amount due in 12 Months: %', to_char(bal_num, '$999.99');
   FOR i IN 1 .. total_mon_amt LOOP
      bal_num := bal_num - mon_pay_amt;
      RAISE NOTICE '%', format('Payment Number: %s Due Date: %s Payment Amount: %s Balance %s'
                             , i
                             , payment_due_date
                             , mon_pay_amt_text
                             , to_char(bal_num, '$990.99'));
      payment_due_date := payment_due_date + interval '1 month';  -- increment after?
   END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

But consider a set-based approach with `generate_series()` instead of the loop:

```sql
DO
$$ 
DECLARE
   start_date date := '2021-01-01';
   payment_due_date date := start_date;
   mon_pay_amt numeric := 10;
   mon_pay_amt_text text :=  to_char(mon_pay_amt, '$99.99');
   total_mon_amt int := 12;
   bal_num numeric := mon_pay_amt * total_mon_amt;
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE '%'
   , (SELECT 'Total Amount due in 12 Months: ' || to_char(bal_num, '$999.99') || E'\n'
          || string_agg(format('Payment Number: %s Due Date: %s Payment Amount: %s Balance: %s'
                             , i
                             , payment_due_date + interval '1 month' * (i-1)
                             , mon_pay_amt_text
                             , to_char(bal_num - mon_pay_amt * i, '$990.99'))
                        , E'\n')                     
      FROM   generate_series(1, total_mon_amt) i
      );
END
$$;
```